# Is there any other way to delete multiple files from a sub folder if S3DirectoryInfo is not available in a particular version of .Net Framework?

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-sdk, delete-file

Is there any other way to delete multiple files from a sub folder if S3DirectoryInfo is not available in a particular version of .Net Framework?

I have used DeleteObjectAsync but the sub folder gets deleted only if it has one file in it. If it contains multiple file ... I am calling the function multiple times which does not seem ideal.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the IDs of the objects, you can delete multiple objects - like all of the objects in your subfolder, with the [DeleteObjectsAsync](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/S3/MS3DeleteObjectsDeleteObjectsRequest.html) method

[There is an example in .NET also:](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-library/latest/ug/s3_example_s3_DeleteObjects_section.html)

```
            DeleteObjectsRequest multiObjectDeleteRequest = new DeleteObjectsRequest();
            multiObjectDeleteRequest.BucketName = bucketName;

            foreach (var key in keys)
            {
                multiObjectDeleteRequest.AddKey(key.Key);
            }

            // Execute DeleteObjectsAsync.
            // The DeleteObjectsAsync method adds a delete marker for each
            // object deleted. You can verify that the objects were removed
            // using the Amazon S3 console.
            DeleteObjectsResponse response;
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Executing NonVersionedDelete...");
                response = await client.DeleteObjectsAsync(multiObjectDeleteRequest);
                Console.WriteLine("Successfully deleted all the {0} items", response.DeletedObjects.Count);
            }
            catch (DeleteObjectsException ex)
            {
                DisplayDeletionErrors(ex);
                throw; // Some deletions failed. Investigate before continuing.
            }

            // This response contains the DeletedObjects list which we use to delete the delete markers.
            return response.DeletedObjects;
```